# How to deal with chromosomes of different lengths genes in genetic algorithm?

Tags: genetic-algorithms

If I have 6 products ($x$) and 11 manufacturers ($y$) 
some products manufactured by some of these manufacturers;
($x,y$) may equal none or any other value.

For each combination of $x$ and $y$ there is and expected values for cost, time and transportation petrol according to distance between the manufacturer and the work site.

I have two problems to use binary genetic algorithm (GA) to find the Pareto sets of these combinations:

1. the gene represent the product contain only 3 digits ($6<7$) and for
   gene used to represent the manufacturer it is 4 digits ($8<11<16$) so
   the chromosome is of 7 digits. the problem is that in all examples
   those I have reviewed the length of genes are equal. so will this be
   a problem for solving this issue.
2. assume product $x_1$ and $x_5$ are not manufactured by $y_3$ and $y_7$ that means
   the fitness function of $(x_1,y_3)$ and $(x_5,y_7) = 0$ and since
   the problem is minimization the solution may be trapped in these two
   points. the question how such cases can be solved?

Thanks for your expected valuable help.

Comment: It isn't clear what problem you're trying to solve. Is the idea that you must manufacture some number of each of the six products, and the objective is to assign each to a manufacturer? For question #1, it doesn't matter if the genes are the same length. Which genetic operation are you unsure about how to handle with variable length genes? If we have more information, we can do a better job of answering the question.